# Field Calculator error: "calculated value is invalid"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.5

I'm getting the following error when trying to calculate a field:

[image]

I'm just trying to calculate all the selected records to equal a value I specify, a simple two-letter zoning code.  So the field calculator expression is simply field = value (I'm not trying to make it equal another field or use a mathematical espression).  The field is string type, length 10, which should be long enough for two letters.  The field does not have a domain assigned to it.  I get the same error whether I'm in an editing session or not.  This should be easy - what's going on?

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of both involved field's properties?

Comment: I figured it out.  I simply needed to add double quotes around the specified value.  Still, the error message was misleading and confusing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a string value (which it sounds like it is since you said two-LETTER zoning code), you need to put quotation marks around the value like: field = "value".

Comment: Yeah, that was kinda stupid of me to overlook something like that...thanks.